# Unable to create '/git/index.lock': File exists - but it doesn't

Tags: windows, git, git-rebase, sourcetree

I'm getting this message when trying to rebase interactively using source tree.

```
If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

> fatal: Unable to create 'X:/sources/project/.git/index.lock': File
>   exists.

The problem is that **X:/sources/project/.git/index.lock** doesn't exist

All the other solutions on SO didn't work for me since they all say to remove this file.

Comment: If you don't see it, probably you're not looking in the same place git is.

Comment: Where exactly did you look at? What makes you think the file does not exist?

Answer (score 13):

I'm on a Mac and ran into basically the same issue.
When running `git rebase -i master`, I received an error:

> fatal: Unable to create 'path/to/file/.git/index.lock': File exists.

The **index.lock** file didn't exist in my **.git/** directory.  But there was an **index** file (no filetype extension). So I aborted the rebase.

After a ton of searching, I finally decided to just create the file:
`touch .git/index.lock`

I tried rebasing again, but that didn't fix the issue (this time the file really did exist).  So I removed it:
`rm .git/index.lock`

That did the trick.  The rebase had conflicts this time (which was odd since I aborted the rebase previously), but I just addressed each conflict and then let the rebase continue:
`git rebase --continue`

I hope this helps someone else who ends up in a similar situation.

Comment: I am having the same issue, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Use `rm -rf X:/sources/project/.git/index.lock` to remove the lock and save yourself a headache. Also, the `index.lock` exists, however, the `.git` folder is hidden. So, use `ls -la X:/sources/project/.git` to see the content of a hidden folder.

Comment: There are cases in which index.lock simply doesn't exist, at least before one starts to rebase. It's not in the hidden .git folder. I'm now wrestling with that problem myself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using Github Desktop.  I watched the .git directory and the index.LOCK file would appear and disappear.  It never persisted for long, so was not there to delete.  I investigated a little as other solutions online did not work for me and found that comparing permissions to folders that I was able to commit they had one difference:  the .git folder that gave me the error had full control like the others, but it was *inherited* from its parent.  I went to properties->security->advanced and removed then re-added the permissions without inheriting them from the parent.  After that I was able to commit my changes without an error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is really strange, but for me, the following worked:

- Create the file .git/index.lock from Windows explorer
- Delete the file again (from git bash, I don't know if this is important)

Then, the command I was executing (`git rebase --continue`, in my case) succeeded. I have no idea why this procedure worked, though. This should not make **any** difference...

Answer (score 0):

I disabled indexing of the `.git` folder and it helped to me to get rid of the message

Answer (score 0):

@Manza: I came across the same issue. There is no index.lock file existing and still it throws an error related to file existence.

I created a patch of my changes and did a clone again. Now when I do a commit, it works all fine. I know this is not the right direction. But this is the go to when the index.lock doesn't get created and still we get this error.

Answer (score 0):

for ios mac remove rm -rf from this location .git/modules/ios  or can manual delete
Step —
1)-Open terminal .
2)-Open project file location.
3)-Rum command - defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES.
Now u can see hidden file in Mac OS.
4)-Rum command -    cd .git/modules/ios (In my case I am running React code).
5)-Now either open folder and delete index.lock or use “rm” command .
6)-Thats its - now try to commit and push .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Mac. In a Terminal window:

```
cd path/to/file/.git
touch index.lock
```

In GitHub Desktop, click **Continue Merge** (it will error again). Switch back to Terminal:

```
rm index.lock
```

Switch to GitHub Desktop and **Continue Merge** worked.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly check out whether you have index.lock file inside .git(hidden folder) in the project file.
if so, delete index.lock file or.

Create a new index.lock file inside .git in your repository and delete it.
This will help you to commit further.

Comment: This question is over 7 years old, and several existing answers already make this suggestion. Please don't repeat answers.